# Adding ggplot2 legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I've been trying to find an answer to my problem but I couldn't solve it with what I found in the forum. I know the key it's do the mapping right (or at least that is what I understood from previous msgs).

Here is my code:

```
  dat <- data.frame(
  Individuals = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10),
  Year = c(0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 3),
  end = c(15, 10, 15, 6, 10, 8, 15, 6, 9, 5))

  Person_time_R <- ggplot(dat) + 
  geom_segment(aes(x=Year, y=Individuals, xend=end, yend=Individuals), 
               color=c("blue","red","red","blue","red","red","blue","red","red","red"), 
  size=2) +
  scale_y_reverse() + 
  ggtitle("Person-time") +
  xlab("Years") + 
  ylab("Individuals") +
  theme(
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size=26, face="bold"),
    axis.title.x = element_text(size=20),
    axis.title.y = element_text(size=20)
    ) +
  scale_y_discrete(limits=c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0,16)) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits=c( 0, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15))
```

I would like to have a legend to separate the "red" and "blue" lines... How could I do that?

Comment: What does `red` and `blue` mean in your plot?

Comment: @ycw `blue` and `red` mark two different types of observations, between the 10 studied.
So `Individuals = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)`
Could be grouped like this: `c(1,2,2,1,2,2,1,2,2,2)`
I don't know if I'm clear enough /=

Comment: Add the data that you want to color by to your data frame in a column, call it, say, `observation_type`. Then add `color = observation_type` to your `aes()`. Then the legend will be created automatically.

Answer (score 1):

To show the color as a legend, you can add a column showing the type, then mapped to the `aes` in `geom_segment`. Finally, use `scale_color_manual` to specify name and color.

```
dat$Type <- c(1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2)

ggplot(dat) + 
  geom_segment(aes(x=Year, y=Individuals, xend=end, yend=Individuals, colour = factor(Type)), 
               size = 2) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("blue", "red"), name = "Type")
```

Comment: To complete ycw's answer, I'd also recommend to use the actual name of each "Type" in the data frame (and ideally factorize it), so that it will be directly shown as such in the legend: e.g., `dat$Type <- factor(c("TypeA", "TypeB", "TypeB", "TypeA", "TypeB", "TypeB", "TypeA", "TypeB", "TypeB", "TypeB"))`